# Question on countability of a set of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

If A is a set of positive real numbers such that for all sequences $(a_n)$ where each element is distinct and $a_j \in A, \forall j$:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i = 0$$ Show that A is countable.

Idrk where to start, any help would be great! 
(I mean I have figured out a few things about the sequence $(a_i)$ but these do not seem very useful.)
**Edit**
I have noticed the following till now:
Since $a_i >0 \forall i$ means that the mean is always greater than 0. So if it converges to 0 implies that the sequences ${\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_j }$ is decreasing. This would further mean that $\forall n, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i > \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} a_i$ which would simplify to $a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i$. I don't know if what I have done is right or not.

Comment: Tell us what you have figured out. It will at least show us that you have put some thought into this.

Comment: Right, yh. I noticed that since $a_i >0 \forall i$ means that the mean is always greater than 0. So if it converges to 0 implies that the sequences ${\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_j }$ is decreasing. This would further mean that $\forall n, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i > \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} a_i$ which would simplify to $a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i$. I don't know if what I have done is right or not.

Comment: @FutileFuton: You should put these thoughts in the original post, not just the comments, thanks!

Comment: Just because a sequence converges to $0$, that doesn't mean that it is decreasing! For instance, $(\frac12,0,\frac13,0,\frac14,0,\ldots)$

Comment: Ah Yh that is what I thought, but all the terms in the sequence are necessarily positive, which is why I concluded that. But I might have overlooked the possibility that there might be a sequence that actually converges to 0 in this case as well. Thanks!

Comment: @FutileFuton Consider e.g. $${1\over 2}, {2\over 2}, {1\over 3}, {2\over 3}, ..., {1\over n}, {2\over n}, ....$$ This converges to zero but is not decreasing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah right, thanks! That seems like a very obvious counterexample now that I think of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Define $A_k=\{x\in A\;|\;x\ge1/k\}$. What can you say about the cardinality of $A_k$?

Comment: Thanks! If we take a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A_k$ such that all terms are distinct, then $\forall n, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_j>=\frac{1}{k}$ but this would be absurd as the mean has to converge to 0, meaning A_k is empty? I am sorry, I am probably being very dumb right now.

Comment: Or wait, it can also be finite, as then selecting such a sequence wouldn't be possible. Regardless, A is the countable union of finite sets, thus the countable union of countable sets, thus countable?

Comment: @FutileFuton: Exactly. Each $A_k$ has to be finite, so their union is countable.